# How to find $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{t}g(s)P(T<t-s)ds$?

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $T$ be a random variable, I want to find $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{t}g(s)P(T<t-s)ds$, where $g$ is a continuous function.

I think I should use the fundamental theorem of calculus, but it looks weird, thanks for any help.

Comment: You can try using the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule): $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(s,t)\, ds = f(b(t),t)b'(t) - f(a(t), t)a'(t) + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,t)\, ds.$$

Comment: So do i just see $g(s)P(T<t-s)$ as $f(s,t)$ as what you mention?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it.

Comment: You're welcome! $\ddot{\smile}$